# How to SQL Query text access a Single quotes/apostrophes with "IN" operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, apostrophe, single-quotes

I'm trying to insert some text data into a table in SQL Server.
The text includes a single quote(') like (New CCTest's,Test Security's..).

I am using IN operator in where query like below.

```
SELECT * FROM CostCenters acc WHERE acc.CCName IN ('New CCTest's','Test Security's')
```

but it throw me errors : Incorrect syntax near 's'.

Also I have tried using double quotes, but it threw me some errors.

```
SELECT * FROM CostCenters acc WHERE acc.CCName IN ('New CCTest"s','Test Security"s')
```

How do I escape that?

Comment: Just duplicate the single quotes: `SELECT * FROM CostCenters acc WHERE acc.CCName IN ('New CCTest''s','Test Security''s')`

Comment: or use a backshash `\'`